# How to sort output from SQL statements combined with union

Tags: sql, sybase

I have statements

```
SELECT a FROM X UNION
SELECT b FROM Y UNION
SELECT c FROM Z;
```

I want the outbut to be orderd so that first come rows from a, then b and finaly c. I have tried to use `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` but I keep getting errors and fail to see the logic, how it should work.

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
select a
from (
  SELECT a, 1 as display_order FROM X
  UNION ALL
  SELECT b, 2 FROM Y 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT c, 3 FROM Z
) w
order by display_order
```